# ¿Cómo ejecutar una función u otra mediante parámetros en c++?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, exec

Me pidieron realizar un programa que invoque a la orden "ls -al /usr/bin" con las
funciones "exec" tal como se indica:

`$./programa opción`

Donde opción, puede ser:

- -l, invocar a la orden ls con la función execl.
- -v, invocar a la orden ls con la función execv.
- -lp, invocar a la orden ls con la función execlp.

El código que diseñe fue el siguiente, pero lo ejecuta, le mande o no un parámetro.

```
 
int main(char funcion) {

  if(funcion == "-l") 
  {
    execl("/usr/bin", ls, -al);
  }
  
  if(funcion == "-v") 
  {
    execv("/usr/bin", ls, -al);
  }
  
  if(funcion == "-lp") 
  {
    execlp("/usr/bin", ls, -al);
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me extraña que siquiera te ejecute algo, porque el código no debería compilar.

---

Cosas a tener en cuenta:

- En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) los literales de texto tienen como tipo `char[letras + 1]` que es una formación<sup>1</sup> de caracteres.
- Así pues el literal `"-l"` tiene como tipo `char[3]`.
- Por otro lado, la variable `funcion` tiene como tipo `char`.
- Así que, en todos tus `if` estás comparando un `char` contra un `char[tamaño]`, lo cuál ni siquiera debería compilar.

Eso sin tener en cuenta que tu función `main` no es estándar, por lo que el compilador también debería rechazarla, sólo existen dos variantes de `main` aceptadas:

1. `int main()`.
2. `int main(int, char **)`.

En resumen: todo tu código es incorrecto y ningún compilador serio lo compilaría. Probablemente querías hacer esto:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  if (argc == 2)
  {
    const std::string comando = argv[1];

    if (comando == "-l") 
    {
      execl("/usr/bin", ls, -al);
    }
    else if (comando == "-v") 
    {
      execv("/usr/bin", ls, -al);
    }
    else if (comando == "-lp") 
    {
      execlp("/usr/bin", ls, -al);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tienes razón la verdad es que lo andaba haciendo en el editor de textos de ubuntu y no me había dado cuenta. Disculpa en el caso de los atributos "ls" y "-al", me marca que no están definidos ¿Sabes que debo hacer ahí?

Comment: No se qué son los *atributos* `"ls"` y `"-al"`; eso es algo de tu código.